# Where should the following visual basic code be inserted in a Windows Form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

### My Problem

I have read a few chapters, and researched a few websites but none of which fulfil my question, which is where should I put this If statement

```
Public LoginName As String
Public Password As String

LoginName = txtUserName.Text
Password = txtPassword.Text

If (LoginName = "" Or Password = "") Then
        btnSubmit.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("G:\Product\ElderlyEmail\ElderlyEmail\Images\stopbutton.gif")
    Else
        btnSubmit.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("G:\Product\ElderlyEmail\ElderlyEmail\Images\GoButton.gif")
    End If
```

The idea is once the user has finished inputting text into both text-boxes the image on the button changes from a no-go to a green-submit button but unsure what declaration it would go under and which element. I have tried several form elements and declarations but not having the desired effect that I would like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea is once the user has finished inputting text into both
>   text-boxes the image on the button changes from a no-go to a
>   green-submit button

You can use many [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_methods.aspx) to achieve this behavior. Perhaps the [OnLostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onlostfocus.aspx) of the `txtPassword` textbox is more suitable since you want the validation to take place when user has finished typing. You could also use the [OnTextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0bhdw6s.aspx) method on each of your textboxes so the validation will run every time the user is typing.

Comment: See my comment below about Validating and Validated.

Comment: @deadlyvices - That's the way I had used it at the past. You' re right, since there are specific events for the validation. Thanks for mentioning it :).

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Validated and Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) events.  They are specifically designed to handle this kind of situation and will fire when you want them to, when you specify `CausesValidation=True`.  OnLostFocus is far too imprecise for this kind of work.

Answer (score -2):

I would maybe do it in javascript

```
    <input type="text" id="loginName" name="loginName" value="" onchange="showGo();" />
    <input type="text" id="loginPasword" name="loginPassword" value="" onchange="showGo();" />


    <table>
    <tr id="nogo">
      <td><input type="image" src="G:\Product\ElderlyEmail\ElderlyEmail\Images\stopbutton.gif" width="60" height="60" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="go">
      <td><input type="image" src="G:\Product\ElderlyEmail\ElderlyEmail\Images\GoButton.gif" width="60" height="60" /></td>
    </tr>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var LName = '';
    var LPass = '';

    showGo()
    {
      LName = document.getElementById('loginName').value;
      LPass = document.getElementById('loginPass').value;

        if (LName != '' && LPass != '')
         {
           document.getElementById('go').style.display = 'inline';
           document.getElementById('nogo').style.display = 'none';
         }
        else
         {
           document.getElementById('go').style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById('nogo').style.display = 'inline';
         }

    }



</script>
```

Comment: He's writing a VB Forms application not a Web application!